# Rgdal installation failed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, rgdal

I have been trying to install `rgdal` from RStudio Version 1.0.44 on ubuntu 16.04 then I was getting the **gdal-config not found** error. I resolved this by installing the `libgdal1-dev` & `libproj` packages but now i'm getting the following  error. Someone help me resolve this.

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/home/hetch/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so.1: undefined symbol:_ZN4geos4geom18IntersectionMatrixC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE 
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/hetch/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 6):

I have had some issues trying to install rgdal package but finally I succeeded.
My problem was that `gdal` > 2.0 is needed, and it does not ship with ubuntu 16.04 by default, so extra packages are needed.

I ended up installing  the following packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal libgdal1-dev
```

Additionally, `r` > 3.3 is needed too, so I ended up updating ubuntu's default `r-base` installation like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cran.rediris.es/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt update
```

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: This didn't work for me..

<code> * installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
  ** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ...
  configure: rgdal: 1.3-4
  ...
  checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
  checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.11.3
checking GDAL version >= 1.11.4... no
  configure: error: upgrade GDAL to 1.11.4 or later
  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
  * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal’
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
</code>

Answer (score 0):

For Rh6, you have just to install:

```
yum install proj-devel-4.8.0-4.1.x86_64.rpm
```

N.B: in my case, my server is not connected to internet, So I download the package from repo to my local machine and then I copied it to my server.