# trouble in installing rgdal on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, rgdal

I have been trying to install rgdal on R 3.4.2 (RStudio 1.1.383) and ubuntu 16.04 but it always end with a problem.

I have followed many recommendations like  manually installing the dependencies like libproj-dev  or my last try by using [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation).

I was able to install gdal 1.11.3 but it's not sufficient.

Here is the output when I write

```
    install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", configure.args=c('--with-proj-include=/usr/local/include','--with-proj-lib=/usr/local/lib'))

Installing package into ‘/home/tupac/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
essai de l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1648779 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.2-15
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 691
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.11.3
checking GDAL version >= 1.6.3... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/share/gdal/1.11/pcs.csv readable... yes
configure: -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -I/usr/local/include 
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/tupac/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

The error "proj_api.h not found" has also been found in the same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation) but the solution given does not work in my case while it seems to work for many other users.

thank you for helping me in fixing this problem.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that `sudo apt install libproj-dev` is to be installed from the terminal, not in the R session ?

Comment: Yes indeed. I've run almost everything with the terminal.

Comment: And `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev` ?

Comment: Yes and it gives me the same error message ("proj_api.h not found") as in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally been able to find a solution.

I followed the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981858/rgdal-installation-failed-on-ubuntu-16-04/46427778#46427778)

The miracle code is

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal libgdal1-dev
```

thank you for your help