# rgdal installation error on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10

I am trying to install rgdal library on R, but I am facing some difficulties. Maybe I is a naive error or pure newbie :P. I am running:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu ; Description:   Ubuntu 17.10 ; Release: 17.10 ; Codename:   artful

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer" ; 
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing ;
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

When I try **install.packages('rgdal')** the following error shows:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/jonathan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.2-18.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1650578 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.2-18
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 718
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/jonathan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpt88o8k/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981858/rgdal-installation-failed-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382368/rgdal-installation-difficulty-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts), but none was helpfull.
Thank you for the support.

Comment: »»error: gdal-config not found«« : Is gdal installed ? .... `sudo apt install libgdal-dev` : Provides /usr/bin/gdal-config

Comment: Oh! That solved the problem! Thank you very much! Can you put as an answer it so I can close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error: gdal-config not found

Is gdal installed ? ....

Solution : `sudo apt install libgdal-dev` : Provides /usr/bin/gdal-config